# How can a binary installed with cargo install be removed?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How can a crate like `rustfmt` be removed after being installed with `cargo install`

Comment: because I forgot the word uninstall and `cargo help` does not list `cargo uninstall`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global binary crates like `rustfmt` can be removed with the command `cargo uninstall [options] <spec>`. Use `cargo help uninstall` to get more detail.