# How can I downgrade or install an older version of a tool I installed with `cargo install`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to install Xargo v0.3.10 on my machine. The current version of Xargo is v0.3.11 and it is installed by the `cargo install xargo` command. How can I install an older version of Xargo?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`cargo install --version 0.3.10 xargo`

Reading the help for the `cargo` tool is very useful:

```
$ cargo install --help
cargo-install
Install a Rust binary

USAGE:
    cargo install [OPTIONS] [--] [crate]...

OPTIONS:
        --version <VERSION>      Specify a version to install from crates.io

[... snip ...]
```

If you wish to downgrade the version of the tool, you'll need to add the `-f` / `--force` flag:

```
-f, --force                  Force overwriting existing crates or binaries
```

See also:

- [Does cargo install have an equivalent update command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34484361/155423)
- [How can a binary installed with cargo install be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44664638/155423)

Comment: You'll also need `--force` if you want to downgrade an already-installed package.

Comment: is `-f` required anymore? I haven't ever used it and my binary packages get updated fine when I just `cargo install packagename` to update it again

Comment: @DexieTheSheep probably not. I vaguely recollect that changing but can't find a commit now.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the `cargo install crate@version` syntax:

```
cargo install xargo@0.3.10
```

The benefit of this is now you can install multiple packages in one go:

```
cargo install pkg-a@0.6 pkg-b@0.9
```

And as far as I can tell, `-f` doesn't seem to be necessary anymore for downgrading as of time of posting.